# Finding asymptotic relationship between: $\frac {\log n}{\log\log n} \overset{?} = (\log (n-\log n))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

> Given $f(n)=\frac {\log n}{\log\log n} , g(n)= (\log (n-\log n))$, what is the relationship between them $f(n)=K (g(n))$ where "K" could be $\Omega,\Theta,O$

I thought of taking a log to both sides and see what we get:

$\log\frac {\log n}{\log(\log n)}= \log(\log n) -\log[\log(\log n)]  \overset{?} = c\log(\log (n-\log n))$

It looks like the RHS is smaller than: $\log(\log (n-\log n)) \le \log(\log n)$

And since $\log[\log(\log n)] < \log(\log n)$ then $\log(\log (n-\log n)) \le \log(\log n) - \log[\log(\log  n)] $

But it's actually $O$, and I can't find a way to show it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at $g(n)$:
$$
g(n) = \log(n-\log n) = \log n + \log\left(1-\frac{\log n}{n}\right) = \log n + o(1)
$$
using the fact that $\frac{\log n}{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ and $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1$.

So $g(n) = \Theta(\log n)$. But $f(n) = \frac{\log n}{\log\log n} = o(\log n)$.

Comment: How did you expand the log like that? $\log(n-\log n) = \log n + \log\left(1-\frac{\log n}{n}\right) $

Comment: To add to your method: one issue is that $O(\cdot)$ (and etc.) relations are not well-preserved by taken logarithms or exponentiating. A classic example is $n+\log n = \Theta(n)$, but $2^{n+\log n} = n2^n \neq  \Theta(2^n)$. So you *do& have $\log f(n) = \Theta(\log g(n))$,but this does not imply that $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ (the low-order additive difference terms in the former become multiplicative in the latter, and they are not constant.)

Comment: Corrected comment (the comment explaining the answer was not consistent with the answer, and was incorrect): $$\log (n - \log n) = \log\left(n\left(1-\frac{\log n}{n}\right)\right) = \log n + \log\left(1-\frac{\log n}{n}\right)$$ where the second step follows from $\log ab = \log a + \log b$.

Comment: Do you use  $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1$ for the $\log\left(1-\frac{\log n}{n}\right) $?

Comment: To say that $\log(1-\frac{\log n}{n})\to 0$  when $n\to\infty$. (Since we have $\frac{\log n}{n}\to 0$, and that fact formalizes that $\log(1-\frac{\log n}{n})\sim_{n\to\infty} -\frac{\log n}{n}$). If this is obvious to you, discard it -- I wrote that for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Another question about what you said, so not every monotone increasing function keeps an asymptotic relationship? I assume only linear ones do?

Comment: You refer to the comments about exponentiating the $O(\cdot)$? It's not entirely clear to me, but I'd say any monotone polynomial should. At least, powers do, iirc: if $0\leq f(n) \leq Cg(n)$ for $n\geq N$, then $f(n) ^k \leq C^\prime g(n)^k$ for $n\geq N$, for any fixed $k> 0$ and $C^\prime = C^k$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log n\bigg/\log(\log n)}{\log(n-\log n)}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log n}{\log(\log n)\log(n-\log n)}=
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log n}{\bigg(\log n+\log(1-\frac{\log n}{n})\bigg)\log(\log n)}
=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log n}{\log(\log n)\log n}=
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\log(\log n)}=0$$